# Error 1783 - instsrv.exe REMOVE from Win2k3

Tags: service, windows-server-2003, uninstallation, instsrv

My applications installer offers the user the ability to run the application as a service through use of the `srvany.exe` application.  To remove the application on uninstall, I've been using the application `instsrv.exe` with the following command:

> instsrv "myservice" REMOVE

On Windows Server 2003, I encounter error 1783.

Any ideas on what is causing this problem?  Am I using the wrong approach for `Win2k3`?

Comment: It looks like the error is referencing a file "instsrv.c" which it's trying to load from the CD drive ... maybe there's a component which doesn't exist on this particular machine.

*T00z - thanks for the advice ... I'll definitely enforce a stop service before removing its registry entry

Comment: This looks like a serverfault question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same with Rk-Tools 2003 and 2000 and I get the same error both times. 
But after removing the registry-parameters manually after the next reboot the services (I tried out several constellations) were gone.
Please think about stopping the service before(!) you're gonna delete the registry-entries, because otherwise the service will not accept any further commands.
Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - references to instsrv.c is just an error message (it tells you where the error has actually happened in the source code). I think (but I am not sure) that this 1783 error occurs when it tries to enumerate services but hits an overflow error (too many services installed?)

A better approach would be to use sc.exe:

```
SC STOP servicename
SC DELETE servicename
```